# How to compare two string indexes in swift 4

Tags: swift, string, swift4

I'm trying to find whether the character "S" or "C" appears in a string.  At least one will be in the string but not necessarily both.

```
let S = codeZ.characters.index(of: "S")
        let C = codeZ.characters.index(of: "C")

        if (C == nil) || S < C {
            nextView.sequential_flag = true
            nextView.continuous_flag = false
        }
        else if S == nil || (C < S) {
            nextView.sequential_flag = false
            nextView.continuous_flag = true
        }
```

I'm getting the error : Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'String.CharacterView.Index?' (aka 'Optional') operands

In my experience with swift this usually means something else if wrong.
Also I've tried changing the if statements to this below.

```
if (C == nil) || S?.encodedOffset < C?.encodedOffset {
            nextView.sequential_flag = true
            nextView.continuous_flag = false
        }
```

And I got the error : Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands.

Any help on how to do this is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `S` is `nil` or not and provide a **fallback value** to `C`. Then you can compare the two non-optional values.

```
if let S = S, S.encodedOffset < (C?.encodedOffset ?? Int.max) {
    nextView.sequential_flag = true
    nextView.continuous_flag = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask what happens when C is nil but S isnt?  I still need that to pass.

Comment: One quick thing, shouldn't the optional value be like 9999 rather than 0 to be sure to pass?  Otherwise thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: Depends on what the desired comparison result for a fallback case is. If you want it to be true when `C` is nil, use `Int.max` for a fallback value.